# Как сделать, чтобы <textarea> после обновления страницы перематывалась вниз?

Tags: html, css, css3, textarea

В теге `textarea` хранится большое количество тескта, больше чем сама `textarea` и после обновления страницы ползунок всегда переходит вверх, в начало текста. Как сделать, чтобы изначально текст перематывался вниз?

Answer (score 1):

Установите положение прокрутки равное высоте прокрутки:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
});
```

```html
<textarea style="height: 160px; width: 100px; font-size: 24px;">В теге textarea хранится большое количество тескта, больше чем сама textarea и после обновления страницы ползунок всегда переходит вверх, в начало текста. Как сделать, чтобы изначально текст перематывался вниз?</textarea>
```